# Unable to override model class, only this file has problem

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, class

I am overriding Worldpay Model class that create xml request file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\RedirectOrder" type="Company\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\RedirectOrder" />
    </config>
```

Model code:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * @copyright 2017 Sapient
     */
    namespace Company\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder;

    use Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\Config\ThreeDSecureConfig;

    /**
     * Build xml for RedirectOrder request
     */
    class RedirectOrder extends \Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\RedirectOrder
    {
//code here
    }
```

I am unable to override this piece of code.
As I do the same thing for another file its override successfully but this RedirectOrder is not.
[Please refer complete file that I want to override.](https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG/blob/master/Model/XmlBuilder/RedirectOrder.php)

updated constructor code:

```
public function __construct(array $args = array())
    {
         $this->threeDSecureConfig = new \Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\Config\ThreeDSecure();

        $this->tokenRequestConfig = new \Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\Config\TokenConfiguration($args['tokenRequestConfig']);
        $this->shopperId = $args['shopperId'];

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to override"? please explain what your error is

Comment: My new class code is not executing, di.xml <preference is not working

Comment: there are no errors main "\Sapient\Worldpay\Model\XmlBuilder\RedirectOrder" is executing everytime

Comment: is the module enabled? did you clean your DI-cache?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that my module is running and DI-Check all good

Comment: do you use another constructor in your class? it's really hard to tell you what the error is with seeing more. you have to debugg this yourself

Comment: Yes, I am using another constructor in my class

Comment: please provide the code

Comment: Updated.
Did you referred this original class? https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG/blob/master/Model/XmlBuilder/RedirectOrder.php

Comment: @Charlie what you have changed in constructor. Actually i have not found any change.

Comment: did not changed anything just copy pasted the orginal one. I tried by removing it too. no success